# Test Result Management and Reporting tool

Tags: automated-testing, data-analysis

I'm looking for a some sort of management/reporting tool that collects the results of tests, stores them for reporting, then lets users generate reports based on those tests.

We have numerous test running tools that run on a variety of platforms, but all output test results in the JUnit format.  The test are not specific to hardware or platform, but rather generic.  What we would like to do is have an automated (or manual) test run be able to submit it to a central location along with additional information, like platform, OS, hardware configuration and maybe user defined data.  The management/reporting tool would store this data.

Then, a manager would be able to go to the tool and request (or more likely, access a dashboard that developers have setup) an update on the current status.  This could be a list of test results that were run in a particular configuration, or a hardware status, or just the results of specific test(s).

EDIT: I am not looking for software that manages the TESTS.  We already write our own tests in other tools.  I want something that can manage the test RESULTS without having to create the TESTS.  Probably makes my question too specialized...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am very interested in any answers.  I looked a year ago, gave up, and implemented my own system - but it's pretty bare, maintenance is a bear, and I can barely keep it working on top of my other responsibilities.

Answer (score 3):

- [Xqual Studio](http://www.xqual.com/products/xstudio.html) can be one of the option which suites your requirement.
- [HP Quality Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Quality_Center) can be other option.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you to try with [test management](http://www.getzephyr.com) tool named Zephyr.

Comment: Do you have any direct experience with Zephyr?  If so could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: +1 This is the only solution that does exactly what the OP wants, and is DESIGNED to do what the OP wants with very little extraneous functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Jason, check out [Enterprise Tester](http://www.enterprisetester.com). It is a test management tool that allows integration with a number of tools, allowing the storing of tests and results in a single place. Integrate Hudson, Jenkin etc. and get total visability across your quality process for both manual and automated tools.

**NOTE:** Bryce works for the company that sells this tool and didn't mention his affiliation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://testcollab.com

It can store all test executions, test cases, list of testers, configurations etc. etc., there are various other features too which might come handy like issue manager integration and time tracking.

The pricing starts at $25 per use on hosted plans (free trial also available)

Disclaimer: I'm the co-founder of Test Collab.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tool](https://xebialabs.com/products/xl-testview/) that was just launched by a company called [XebiaLabs](https://xebialabs.com/products/xl-testview/)...

I believe the tool is called [TestView](https://xebialabs.com/products/xl-testview/) and does exactly what you are looking for.

> XL TestView is the first test results management and analysis tool
>   that allows you to define and execute tests across your full spectrum
>   of test tools, then aggregate and visualize the results to provide
>   insight into your application's quality.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous integration server might meet your needs.  I suggest looking at Hudson or Jenkins.

Comment: Already using Jenkins to run the tests, but I haven't found a way in Jenkins to aggregate the test results from a variety of jobs and allow querying on them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a custom solution might be the best answer here, I would build a custom database (you could use SQL lite, or similar) then some code to transform the results into the database, then use some cool javascript charting library to give you web based reports. It would take a bit of work but it should be quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

[Zephyr](http://www.getzephyr.com/) has a feature called a ZBot that acts as a execution proxy to run your tests, triggered from "planned unit test" phases in the Zephyr UI.   We implemented a Spring-MVC REST web-service test runner and a user in Zephyr can click a "execute" button on a testcase, and it sends the command through the ZBot and calls our web service to run the tests.  Does exactly what is asked by the PO.   Also, the web-service responds with a JSON packet containing information on where the URL to the test report is and the video of the test sot that Zephyr UI is able to display the results.   Also, Zephyr has its own reporting feature for these tests that gives you an aggregate view of the results of your testing cycles and phases.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - The question didn’t mention whether they are looking for an open source or free solution but if not then [Tesults](https://www.tesults.com) (https://www.tesults.com) does what is being asked for.

No doubt Jason has moved on with his life after five years but most of the answers here still do not actually answer the question. He has a specific requirement where it looks like he already has existing test frameworks set up across various platforms and requires no help with setting up the ‘management’ of tests or writing tests. He simply wants to collate his results and quote

> *submit them to a central location*

so that a human manager can come along and view a report of the results by

> *platform, OS, hardware configuration and maybe user defined
>   data.*

Everything mentioned here is either a test framework (which he has clearly said he does not need) or is far too heavy (management of the whole testing lifecycle).

Sadly he did not mention if he was looking for an open source or free provider, if he was then I still don’t have an answer but I’m using [Tesults](https://www.tesults.com) and it does exactly what Jason wanted. As a matter of integrity for myself and Tesults I should mention I found out about it directly from the developers because I know them and they suggested I post this response.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a lot of different tests and I assume that build in functionality of your continues integration tool does not do the job anymore. The easiest way would be to build yourself what you need.

but I have two questions - why you need that? what do you want to see there in those reports?

Answer (score 0):

Testlink also having good reporting features. It can also integrate with Jira , Selenium so that automation results automatically can update

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some tool that can help you manage test results, I would suggest you use Test Rail. Also, you can consider working on JIRA to keep all your test data managed, right from test case building to managing test results.

Answer (score -1):

There are excellent real-time data dashboards like Geckoboard which can help you manage and report your test results, and that too in real-time. These can be integrated with project management tools like JIRA and you can create custom dashboards for management, and for your team with regular data feeds which will keep these updated, effectively freeing you from the hassle of test result management and reporting. As a technical writer for OnPath Testing, I have written this article on [Geckoboard.](https://onpathtesting.com/?s=geckoboard)

Comment: Ritu, thanks for your help there! I "declined" the flags just so they wouldn't continue to count against the post. Thanks again!